# libsndfile - sf_open(): Undefined references in time.h

Tags: c++, mingw, undefined-reference, portaudio, libsndfile

I am using `libsndfile` and `portaudio` to play audio from a `.wav` file and I am getting some weird undefined reference (in `time.h`...?) errors upon use of `sf_open(const char*, int, SF_INFO*)` Before showing the errors, here is some basic info: I'm using MinGW 3.21 (cannot upgrade due to IDE constraints) on Windows 10, with CMake as my build system. I have verified that the `const char*` passed to `sf_open` is a valid file name and I have checked that no other lines of code are causing this compilation error. Without further ado, have some lovely errors:

```
libsndfile/lib/libsndfile.a(aiff.o): In function time':
c:/dwimperl/c/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32
/4.4.7/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/time.h:242: 
undefined reference to _time32'
```

This is printed several times, probably because the function `time` is used a lot in `sf_open` although I haven't a clue as to why. This happens as well:

```
In function `gmtime':
c:/dwimperl/c/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-
mingw32/4.4.7/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/time.h:240: 
undefined reference to `_gmtime32'
```

These errors imply no correlation between `sf_open` and `time.h`, but I even tried the following,

```
#include<sndfile.h>

int main {
    sf_open(nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

and gotten the same result. I have `libsndfile-1.dll` in the same directory as my compiled binaries, and am linking to both `libsndfile.a` and `libsndfile.dll.a`. I have tried only linking to `libsndfile.a` with the same result. However, I tried linking only to `libsndfile.dll.a` and the program compiled but then crashed, saying:

```
An error occured while using the portaudio stream
Error number: -9984
Error message: Incompatible host API specific stream info
```

I'm not sure whether or not that is something for another question, but I thought I'd mention it, seeing that `sf_open`, the faulty function, seems to do something with stream info. Anyways, this is as far as I've gotten. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at me being such a genius, answering the question by asking it and then not noticing. Sometimes I wonder how I'm still alive. Anyways, it was simple. Don't link `libsndfile.a`, just `libsndfile.dll.a`. That's all. The PortAudio error was something entirely unrelated. Sorry for the idiocy, hope this helps at least one person...?